# How to choose a suitable hamiltonian in hybrid monte-carlo HMC?

Tags: bayesian, sampling, monte-carlo

For example if one were to simulate with MCMC the posterior beta distribution for the beta prior in a beta-binomial, using binomial samples, then what Hamiltonian should be used to decorrelate nearby samples?